# How to get only first "N" elements from postgres through views in Django using jinja

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, jinja2

I am using Django and postgres.

My **views.py** looks like:

```
def home(request):
    title = Scrap.objects
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'headlines': headlines})
```

My **index.html** looks like:

```
 <div class="content"
    style="background:white; color: white; font-family: Verdana;font-weight: 5;text-align: center;">
    {% for headline in headlines.all reversed %}
        <a href="{{ headline.url }}" target="_blank" style="color:black; font-size: medium;" />{{ headline.headlines }}</a>
        <hr style="border-bottom: dotted 1px #000" />
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

With the above code I am getting all the rows from the databse. How can I get only "N" rows?

**I have tried**:

```
{% for headline in headlines.all[:5] reversed %}
```

but it throws an error.

> Could not parse the remainder: '[:5]' from 'headlines.all[:5]'

Comment: you have no reference to `headlines` variable in the given view function. Is that a typo?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are trying to do this in the template rather than the view?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser i am following a tutorial and the tutor is doing in this way. That is the only reason i am doing it in the template.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu nope, this is what i am using. I might be wrong because i am following a tutorial and trying to follow that.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using Jinga2 and not Django? As that syntax looks correct. Can you give us the specific error?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser error is :
Could not parse the remainder: '[:5]' from 'headlines.all[:5]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you got into the wrong tutorial. This answer is may not the *exact answer you may looking for*, but this will give you the idea

```
# views.py
def home(request):
    limit = 5
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()[:limit]
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'queryset': queryset})

# index.html
{% for headline in queryset reversed %}
    {{ headline }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: getting this error:
'ellipsis' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

If you want the latest (last N rows which are added to the database):

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]
```